# How does Remmina folder sharing work in Linux?

Tags: desktop, sharing, rdp

I am trying to mount my local folder to a remote desktop using Remmina. I am not able to do it and I have searched a lot over the web. Can anyone guide how to share the files on my local folder to the remote desktop and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, check the version of Remmina which you have. It should be above '1.2.1' version or use 'remmina-next'. To upgrade your Remmina to remmina-next, open terminal and write the following commands.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libfreerdp-plugins-standard remmina remmina-plugin-rdp
```

After this, the new version of remmina-next will be installed.

Next step will be to go to terminal and type `cd .config/remmina/`

Then open the configuration file and edit it by typing `sudo vi remmina.pref` on the command line

The configuration file will be opened. Search for `sharefolder` under `[remmina]`
 header.

Against the `sharefolder`,  give the path of the folder you want to share with the remote desktop.

That’s it! You should be able to access the specified folder in your Windows VM

The folder will be shown in Windows remote desktop as one of the path/icon along with other locations. (like C drive)

Comment: One can also configure the shared folder using Remmina's GUI by right clicking on the connection, selecting "edit", checking "share folder" and selecting the path to the shared folder on the client.

Comment: After sharing a folder "ClientShare" on the client side with Remmina's GUI, it appeared (after restarting the client and server) on my Ubuntu 18.04 server machine under home/<username>/thinclient_drives/ClientSh . So I guess only the first 8 letters of "ClientShare" have been considered

Comment: "sharefolder" is not  available  in remmina.pref

Comment: Since the OP didn't specify the OS they are connecting too, it should be noted that this answer is Windows-only (using RDP). If you have SPICE or VNC, or SSH, there is still similar option (in the GUI), however I am yet to make it work.